# Keep item animated after unhover

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have an icon that rotates when you hover on it, but only on hover not on 'unhover'.
The animation however stops when removing the cursor from the object.
How can I let it resume the animation even when the cursor isn't on the object anymore?
My Code:

```
.header .logo img {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: transform 0s 0s; 
}

.header .logo img:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    transition: transform 1.2s;
    animation-play-state: running;
}
```

Thank you for helping in advance

Comment: sounds like you want it to rotate all the time . Is that right ?

Comment: @Adarsh no, it should keep rotating until its finished with the animation it would have been doing if the cursor is on the object

Comment: You need javascript for that

Comment: So it's not a question of it 'resuming' the rotation but once hovered it should rotate all the way round even if the hover is removed. Is that right?

Comment: It sounds like @Brentspine wants the animation to start when the the mouse is hovered over the element, and finish (or keep running) even if the mouse is no longer hovering the element.

Comment: Exactly ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some way of the element 'remembering' that it has to carry on rotating.

For that you'll need a bit of Javascript to sense when the mouse is hovering over the element and to sense when the transition has ended. These events will add and remove a class respectively.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('.header .logo img');

function addRotate() {
  div.classList.add('rotate');
}

function removeRotate() {
  div.classList.remove('rotate');
}
div.addEventListener('mouseover', addRotate);
div.addEventListener('transitionend', removeRotate);
```

```css
.header .logo img {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 0s 0s;
}

.header .logo img.rotate {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: transform 1.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300">
  </div>
</div>
```